# ERROR TypeError: date.equals is not a function when i add ngb datepicker in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngb-datepicker

```
ERROR TypeError: date.equals is not a function
```

I get that error on my console, which I don't know how to fix

```
at GlobalsidebarComponent.isRange (globalsidebar.component.ts:45)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (GlobalsidebarComponent.html:26)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14735)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13849)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
```

Date picker screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `ngb-datepicker` does not use the default `Date` object.

> Datepicker uses NgbDateStruct interface as a model and not the native Date object. It's a simple data structure with 3 fields, but note that months start with 1 (as in ISO 8601).

[api](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#date-model)

So to update your date object to a `NgbDate` you have to do:

```
const date = new Date();
const ngbDate = new NgbDate(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate());
```

---

I believe however that you can also tell the module to use the native date. In order to do so, you need to add this to the providers of your `AppModule`:

```
providers: [{provide: NgbDateAdapter, useClass: NgbDateNativeAdapter}]
```

Comment: In this case i got error: Cannot find name 'NgbDateNativeAdapter'

Comment: @preranapandey you do need to do `import {NgbDateAdapter, NgbDateNativeAdapter} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'`

Comment: @preranapandey can you create a stackblitz showing your issue?

Comment: could u give me skype id, so i can easily connect with you, bcz its very urgent to resolve

Comment: where i have to put this code : const date = new Date();
const ngbDate = new NgbDate(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate());